# Iterate through a web element list and click one element at a time

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I try to scrape odds from a betting site using Selenium.
What i try to do is:

1. click on first match to go to match page,
2. get some odds (for final result),
3. go back to the homepage
4. click the second match to do the same.

When i do it outside a loop it's executed without a problem.
But when i try it in a loop it gives me an error:
"Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". It seems like it doesnt recognise the second element of the list to click it.

NOTE: all_matches = is a list with the elements i want to click each time.
Is it a problem that i saved the elements in a list outside the loop?
Or should i do something to load again the homepage?

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aJ0p.png)

Answer (score 0):

I cant see your website so I'll try to explain the best way.

So you have to get all elements using use `find_elements_by_xpath` and then use `len()` to get the number of items. You can then use a loop to click each element.

Code example:

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(<XPATH>) 
for x in range(1, len(items) + 1):
    # You have to find what number changes to select each value and use x.
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(<PATH>).click()
```

If you give me the website and what you want to cycle through I can make a better code example but for now, this is what I can do with the current information.

Comment: Hey @DeadSec,

thanks for the answer, the website is (https://www.betshop.gr/sports/league/stoixima-podosfairo/england-premier-league/1) but dont know if you can open it.
If you mean what number changes inside div[x] i cant because its different every time cause matches are grouped by date. 

So i tried something. It clicks on first element, goes to match page gets the odds, then goes back to homepage and there i can manually write to click the next element and it does. But i must use find element again. Why since i have stored the elements in a list cant i click one at a time?

Comment: @KiriakosDimtsis you have to get the element every time.